# SharePoint online development site for production enhancements

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I got a project where I have to do some design customization and add few functionalities like workflows. I know we should not do these changes directly on production but to make a dev/ staging environment what is the exact way?

One way could be that we can create replica of this SharePoint online site and do changes there. After all changes are done and approve we can move them to production. But in this case also I would like to know how can we create a site's replica and then later sync it to main production site.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach would be to create a dev/staging tenant and grant a subset of people access.  So dev would be the devs, staging would be the devs and qa testers.  Many companies that I've done work for don't want the extra expense so they opt to create separate site collections for dev and staging.  Depending on what you're working on, that might be ok.

If you have an msdn subscription, you could spin up a dev tenant for yourself and separate it out that way.

Then to deploy, if you have everything scripted out, you can automate the deployments.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, right now our site is running on production so is there any way I can create its replica in separate site collection? and then I can do the changes in it?

Comment: Take a look at the PnP provisioning engine on github. It's a way to use PowerShell to provision new sites. You may be able to export a template of your site and use that as the basis of a new site.